# How to test jQuery Mobile changePage with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: jquery-mobile, selenium-webdriver

I want to test with Selenium WebDriver a jQuery Mobile web site with some changePage() statements. If I record the actions with the Selenium IDE and play it, it works fine. But if I do the same actions with WebDriver the changePage() seems to be ignored.

Let me describe it by this small example. Let's assume I have a page like in

http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/YjsPD/

in which a button with id "changePageButton" shall move to another page.

So, for testing with WebDriver I use this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("changePageButton")).click();
```

But the page does not change, instead the simulated click only seems to reload the page. Has anybody tested changePages successfully with WebDriver or an idea?

Regards

Comment: Are you waiting for the page and the JS libs to load before running the WebDriver command, or doing it straight after you call `get(url)`?

Comment: Hello Andrew. I have called the page with driver.get(theUrl) and next command is the driver-click command. Is this wrong? But I nevertheless I found out that almost all functions that are bound to the button, work well. But if the function does a change page it fails, e.g. ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("myfunction();"); works fine as far as myfunction() does not do a $.mobile.changePage("#page2");

Comment: Does it work if you just add a delay before the click? Try 5 secs and we can finesse from there.

Comment: No unfortunately this does not help. If myfunction() contains three commands: 1. alert ("1"), 2. changePage , 3. alert("2) then the alert 1 is shown, and the changePage seems to only reload the full page and shows page 1 again, and alert 2 is shown.

Comment: I wouldn't go down the alert() route for debugging, prefer `console.log()` if you have to. There's probably a 95% consensus that this is likely a timing issue, so please try to rule that out first using delays. If this really is more complex, then a trace log will be handy later.

Comment: Well I have tried it with driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS). And in another attempt I have put Thread.sleep(5000) after calling the page and before the click. Then I did the same with sleep and direct call of the changePage method with the JavaExecutor. And I tried to debug it, but my knowledge to web driver is too limited for this.. Yes, I am very new to Selenium testing, maybe it is some obvious thing that I do not recognize. How to generate a useful trace log if there is no java exception or error?

Comment: Hmm, OK, perhaps we can rule that out then. More thought required!

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your hints. Well it turns out it was a double slash in the URL, produced by the export functionality of Selenium IDE, that was the issue - as "CtrlAltDelicius" wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have exported the test case form Selenium IDE. In this case Selenium produced a method like:

```
@Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/test.html");
  }
```

But the baseUrl is ended with a slash, and test.html starts with a slash, so there are two slashes in the complete URL. In the jqueryMobile code there is a condition check in the method isEmbeddedPage() that compares web hash addresses and finds a difference and goes back to the global page instead of changing to the page2. That's why almost everything works but not the changePage due to this special check.

So if you remove the slash before test.html it should work.

I suppose this is an error in the export functionality of Selenium.

Regards!

Comment: Hello, thank you this was exactly the issue! Maybe it is ugly to produce links like http://base//webpage.html in Selenium, but still its a valid URL, right? Isn't it rather a point that should be fixed in jQueryMobile?